# Calculate days for each years between two dates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, data-science-model

I have a usecase wherein the from and to dates are provided. I need to calculate the total_days in each year and the total orders for each year. I'm currently coding in python
Below is an example

```
OrderNo From_dt   To_dt        
1        6/11/2017  7/8/2019
2        06/02/2018  10/02/2018
```

Target Data that I want to achieve:

Year Total_Days   Total_Orders
2017   300            20
2018   200            10
2019   400            70

I need to dynamically create the years like in the first example 2018 will have 364 days and 2019 will have 190 days.
In the second case since just 1 years is involved I can just fill the 2018 column
Eventually I need to add all the days in 2017, 2018,2019 and so on to get total_days.Similarly total_orders for each year.

I'm confused on how to get started with the above problem.

Comment: Do you mean the number of days between the from_dt and to_dt? Please also show what you've tried and the target dataframe you want to achieve

Comment: You need help others understand. 6/11/2017 is in which format. Is it November or June? In the second case will 2018 have 365 days or 4 days or 4 months(274 days)?
Is your target a table grouped by year and the sum of days and total orders?

`FirstCase  {2017: 203, 2018: 365, 2019: 188}
SecondCase    {2018: 274}`

Are these the values you're looking for?